# Dividing time series by datetime period?

Tags: r

I have some problems splitting a datetime variable into two variables. My time series is a /hour/day/month count of a full year (about 360 days).

I would like to generate one variable that  ranges from the 1st of each month to the 19th of each month and the second variable captures 20 to the rest of the month:

Format:

```
              datetime    hours        var1        var2          var3                 
             2011-01-1   00:00:00 
             2011-01-1   01:00:00  
             ...         ...
             2011-01-1   23:00:00

             2011-01-2   00:00:00 
             2011-01-2   01:00:00
                 ...        ...
             2011-01-2   23:00:00
             ...         ...
             ...         ...
             2011-01-20  01:00:00
                 ...
             2011-01-31  00:00:00
             ...         ...
             2011-12-30  00:00:00
             2011-12-30  01:00:00
             ..          ..
```

Desired Format:

```
                  datetime1              datetime2              var1    var2     var2
             2011-01-1  00:00:00     2011-01-20  00:00:00 
             2011-01-1  01:00:00     2011-01-21  01:00:00 
              ..          ..          ..          ..
             2011-01-19 00:00:00     2011-01-30  00:00:00 
             2011-01-19 01:00:00     2011-01-30  01:00:00
              ..         ..                  ..        ...
              ..         ..                  ..        ...
             2011-12-19 00:00:00     2011-12-30  00:00:00
             2011-12-19 01:00:00     2011-12-30  01:00:00
```

Originally, I was able to produce the datetime variable by:

```
          rbind or rbind.fill ( plyr) two data frames with datetime1 and datetime2
                      df3<-rbind(df1,df2)
```

That is, the original version (two data frames) had these two variables but Im not able to seperate them now.

I just couldt formulate the code...

Comment: It seems you wish to overlap the dates in the "desired format". What would the grouping be done by?

Comment: Please dput() a subset of your data in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to extract the day of the date:

```
xx <- as.Date("2014-12-31")
as.POSIXlt(xx)$mday
```

You can then use the date as a condition to attribute NA to one column and value to the other.

EDIT: Here's the more in-depth version.

```
#Setting up a replicable example
mydata <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(90), ncol=3))
names(mydata)[1:2] <- paste0("time",1:2)
mydata$time1 <- as.Date(NA)
mydata$time2 <- as.Date(NA)
str(mydata)

#Getting 30 consecutive days:
datestring <- rep(Sys.time(), 30)
for(i in 1:30)
 datestring[i]<- Sys.time() + 60*60*24*i
mydata <- cbind(datestring, mydata)

#Doing what I think you're trying to do:
for (i in 1:dim(mydata)[1]){
    if(as.POSIXlt(mydata$datestring[i])$mday <=19)
    {mydata$time1[i] <- mydata$datestring[i]}
    else {mydata$time2[i] <- mydata$datestring[i]}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. But ist not about extracting day from datetime ist about splitting the time series into two time series as illustrated in my example

Comment: @Mamba, I wrote up a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: thx again for your advice. That approaches what Im trying to implement. How do I have to start? Do I have to inlcude as.Date(df$datetime)? and how do you treat hours? I your example its a constant